# Call python class from another Python script

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have 2 Python scripts: 1 is a library and another is a run file

Library.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

'''  The purpose of this test is to test Google's email site '''

class GoogleTest(object):
''' Opens Firefox web browser and navigates to the declared website'''
def open_browser(self,url):
    global driver
    driver=webdriver.Firefox()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.get(url)
def sign_in(self,emailaddr): # Signs in  to googles email
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sign in').click()
    email = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Email")))
    email.send_keys(emailaddr)
    driver.find_element_by_id('next').click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

run.py

```
from Library import GoogleTest
import os,sys

G=GoogleTest()

G.open_browser('https://www.google.com')
G.sign_in('emailssss@gmail.com')
```

> **I get an error that says sign_in takes 2 arguments but only 1 is given**

I do not understand. I thought **self** was an instance. I am not using it as a parameter.

Comment: Is the indentation in your code like you pasted? If so, then it's wrong. You need to indent the methods of `GoogleTest` class. Also, I don't think you have pasted all your code here. And the error is probably due to that other code.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code with proper indentation for methods and doc comments and ran the command `python run.py`, which executed the script successfully.

Can you please add the complete stack trace? If the error mentioned the question really appearing, then, first it should appear for the `open_browser` method itself.

Here are the updated classes:

Library.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

'''  The purpose of this test is to test Google's email site '''

class GoogleTest(object):
    ''' Opens Firefox web browser and navigates to the declared website'''
    def open_browser(self,url):
        global driver
        driver=webdriver.Firefox()
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.get(url)
    def sign_in(self,emailaddr): # Signs in  to googles email
        driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sign in').click()
        email = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Email")))
        email.send_keys(emailaddr)
        driver.find_element_by_id('next').click()
        time.sleep(2)
```

Run.py

```
from Library import GoogleTest
import os,sys

G=GoogleTest()

G.open_browser('https://www.google.com')
G.sign_in('emailssss@gmail.com')
```